# Combinations from an array in set of 6 but not reverse unique

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out a function to get sets of 6 from an array.
I want to get every combination but not the unique combination.
For example if 1,2,3,4,5,6 already exsist 4,5,6,1,2,3 is not needed.
I just want the set of 6 possible combinations that will cover all numbers in the array.

Thank you for the help and your time.

I have tried:

```
function pc_permute($items, $perms = [], &$ret = []) {
    if (empty($items)) {
        $ret[] = $perms;
    } else {
        for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
            $newitems = $items;
            $newperms = $perms;
            list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
            array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
            $this->pc_permute($newitems, $newperms,$ret);
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

but this is not what I want

my array is like:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about this is to `shuffle()` your array. Then copy the array using `array_slice()` from 0 - 5, 1 - 6, etc...

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

shuffle($arr);

$result = [];
for ($x = 0; $x < 6; $x++) {
    $temp = array_slice($arr, $x, 6);
    if ( count( $temp ) < 6 ) $temp = array_merge( $temp, array_slice($arr, 0, 6 - count( $temp ) ) );
    shuffle($temp);
    $result[] = $temp;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

Sample output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 6
            [5] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 7
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 9
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 7
            [4] => 9
            [5] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 9
            [4] => 7
            [5] => 4
        )

)
```